# "nticks" not being respected for xaxis in plotly scene

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, scatter3d

Let's begin with the code:

```
b_min = [-3, 6, 0]
b_max = [24, 24, 9]
n_vertices = [10, 10, 10]

p_a = [-1, 11, 4.5]
p_b = [11, 9, 9]
p_c = [6, 8, 6]
p_d = [-1, 7, 10]

points = [p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d]

df = pd.DataFrame(points, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
figure = px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='y', z='z')
figure.update_layout(scene={
    'xaxis': {'nticks': n_vertices[0], 'range': [b_min[0], b_max[0]]},
    'yaxis': {'nticks': n_vertices[1], 'range': [b_min[1], b_max[1]]},
    'zaxis': {'nticks': n_vertices[2], 'range': [b_min[2], b_max[2]]}
})
figure.show()
```

I **expect** there to be 10 ticks per axis. This is true for axis y and z, but not for x. Why?
[image: the plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation for scatter3d traces [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter3d/), `nticks` is the maximum number of a ticks for an axis, and the actual number of ticks is less than or equal to `nticks`.